# Is it possible to have V1 greater then Vr?

Tags: aircraft-performance, airspeed

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_speeds#V1_definitions), decision speed ($V_1$) is computed taking into account the runway length (and other parameters). If an aircraft uses a long runway (one listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_longest_runways)), there may be enough runway available to stop an aircraft rejecting takeoff at high speed. Thus $V_1$ can be higher than usual, perhaps greater than $V_r$ or $V_2$. Is the situation where $V_1$ is greater than $V_r$ possible?

Comment: See: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3567/258 If Vr is ever less than V1 then Vr will be increased to equal V1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is no.

If you think about V<sub>1</sub> as primarily based on runway length, it is certainly possible for an aircraft to easily reach V<sub>r</sub> long before reaching the "point of no return" as far as stopping distance is concerned.

However, you must also consider the meaning of V<sub>r</sub>. This is when the aircraft is going to rotate. After rotation and leaving the ground, the distance required to still stop on that same runway increases significantly.  For this reason, maximum V<sub>1</sub> is generally considered to be V<sub>r</sub> (see [this discussion](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=750003)).

In large aircraft, rejecting a takeoff after leaving the ground is generally discouraged, unless the pilot feels that the plane could be uncontrollable. It's much safer to continue the takeoff and fly for a normal approach. However, [it can happen](http://avherald.com/h?article=471583da).

In smaller aircraft, it's more reasonable for the aircraft to take off and then land safely (I'm thinking a C172 on one of the low density altitude runways you linked to).

Comment: For smaller aircrafts operating on way oversized strips it is different. Still, mine is a "niptcking"reasoning.

Comment: The "this discussion" link goes to the airliners.net forum homepage.

Comment: @Sean thanks for the correction and heads up on the link. FYI, I'm fixing them by searching the link on the wayback machine, then googling some of the text to find the new location.

Answer (score 4):

Simply no

Rotation comes always after decision :)