# What is the significance of the V1 ground roll of an aircraft?

Tags: v-speeds

What is the significance of a V1 ground roll of an aircraft trying to take off? Why is minimum ground roll is measured in feet? What is the significance of VR (which is greater than V1 but less than V2)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking about in relation to the V1 "ground roll", but this question/answer discusses V1 in depth: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3564/69

Comment: The post that Lnafziger tells the V speeds pretty well, V1 is the "point of no return" at which the pilot is committed to taking off. Vr is where the pilot needs to rotate the nose of the aircraft up so that you can fly, and V2 is when you are flying. V1 "distance" lets the pilot know how far down the runway they can be and still abort. Its measured in feet because runway distances are published in feet.