# Is it possible to determine a rotation speed (Vr) using other known V-Speeds?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, performance-calculation, v-speeds

Is it possible to come up with a good estimate of rotation speed using other known V-Speeds?

*For example: if I know a plane has a `Vs @ 55kt`. and a `Vy @ 75kt`, is there a reasonable method to use to come up with a safe rotation speed?*

This is a general question. I'm not looking for an exact rotation speed calculation (unless one actually exists, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [FAR 23.51](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2002-title14-vol1/pdf/CFR-2002-title14-vol1-sec23-51.pdf) that covers normal, utility, acrobatic, and commuter category airplanes:

> For multiengine landplanes, VR,
>   must not be less than the greater of
>   1.05 VMC; or 1.10 VS1

So 110% of the Vs of a particular configuration works. (Do **not** use for flight.)

---

- Note from @Pondlife: 23.51 has been superseded with [23.2115](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=6021c60900270a9b05abb0152b5b4337&mc=true&node=se14.1.23_12115&rgn=div8) and the quoted definition is no longer there.
- Related: [What makes V1 one or two knots less than Vr on this performance table?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43840/what-makes-v1-one-or-two-knots-less-than-vr-on-this-performance-table/43853#43853)